# Degree to Degree Minutes Seconds (DMS) Conversion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

imagine you have the angle 11.16 degrees.

According to the rapidtables convertor this is equal to 11 degrees 6 minutes and 26 seconds (11degrees 9'36'')

However, I got the answer 11 degrees 6 minutes 216 seconds. I plugged in my answer into the convertor and it got 11.16 degrees. I was wondering if my answer was also acceptable.

Would my answer be correct or would I have to simplify it.

Thanks

Comment: When expressing an angle in D-M-S, the number of minutes and the number of seconds should both always be at least $0$ and less than $60$. It's similar to when you talk about time -- you would never speak of "two hours and sixty-four minutes", you would instead say "three hours and four minutes".

Comment: I'm confused: Is the "11 degrees 6 minutes and 26 seconds" a typo? Your parenthesized form says 11 degrees, 9 minutes and 36 seconds.

Comment: If I had a dime for every time that I saw a question like this one, I'd have 3 dollars and 2340 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,in a sense, but when rounding; anything from 559 to 593 arcseconds ( 9 arcminutes 19 arc seconds, to 9 arcminutes 53 arcseconds), rounds to the nearest hundredth of a degree to 0.16 degrees ( used google).